# What is the point of writing @php @endphp instead of <?php ?> in Laravel Blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

You can write PHP code like below in Laravel.

```
@php
    //
@endphp
```

Alternately you can write,

```
<?php
//
?>
```

What is the difference between about two method? What are the advantages?

For a example when we use to display something, we can use `{{ $name}}`. It can **save developer time** because if we use PHP we have to write `<?php echo $name; ?>`.

But what is the point of writing `@php  @endphp` instead of `<?php ?>`

Comment: I don't think there is any extra benefit of using `@php  @endphp` instead of `<?php ?>`. This is just to maintain consistency of blade syntex

Comment: Some people just prefer to use the `@php` versions so that it's the same as the rest of the blade directives.

Comment: I think there is not much difference in using blade template syntax over php syntax, as per I know auto-escaping is difference in that. In blade template it auto escape string.

Comment: You can save even more developer time writing <?=$name?>, but you wouldn't do that... If you write a blade.php file, you use blade.

Comment: @Amarnasan That's a totally different story. If you have good PHP knowledge you should know that you can't use <?=$name?> if PHP short tag isn't enabled in the server. So, there is a clear disadvantage of writing ?=$name?>.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Long in a short there is absolutely **no** difference.

Its just a directive that keep blade views consistent with other pre defined directives such as **@while @if @foreach** etc.

You can find definition under

> Illuminate/view/Compilers/Concerns/CompilesRawPhp.php

simply it takes expression between 
`<?php ?` tags

```
protected function compilePhp($expression)
    {
        if ($expression) {
            return "<?php {$expression}; ?>";
        }
        return '@php';
    }
```